# Cannot Update code saved in siteassets

Tags: file-upload

I have been trying to update one piece of code saved in siteassets. For some reason, if I try to drag and drop the updated CSS code in, the pop up shows:
[image]
 I click "replace it" and the modified date shows "a few seconds ago"... However, when I open the file, I find that my changes were not made. I have tried to use the "upload" button, and the same outcome. I even synced the library to my computer, and drag and dropped the file from file explorer, to no avail. Why can't I change this file? This has been a reoccurring issue with Javascript files saved in siteassets in the past. Even if I delete the file, and drag the new version in, it doesn't keep the changes. I'm thoroughly confused. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be cache issue.

Open your CSS file in browser. Please do Ctrl-F5 to force a cache refresh.

**F5** may give you the same page even if the content is changed, because it may load the page from cache. 
**Ctrl-F5** forces a cache refresh, and will guarantee that if the content is changed, you will get the new content.
[What requests do browsers' “F5” and “Ctrl + F5” refreshes generate..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385367/what-requests-do-browsers-f5-and-ctrl-f5-refreshes-generate)

Comment: I looked at it today and the change seems to have gone through, if I use the Ctrl+F5 it does fix the issue thank you

Answer (score 1):

If it is updating the modified dates, it sounds like it is working but is merely a browser cache issue. Have you tried doing a hard refresh and/or clearing your browser cache or trying in a private browser tab?

Doing this should resolve the issues you are facing.